# Not booting from hard disk after Installation from USB?

Tags: linux, mount, grub

I downloaded kali 32bit images from  Official Kali website, then installed on my existing windows 7 machine erasing and creating a single partition.

Now, after rebooting

> error: no such device: b8b6b11d-0755-...
>
> ```
> Entering rescue mode...
> grub rescue>
> ```

I couldn't rescue from the boot mode since my keyboard has no  **H** key to type the following to repair grub

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
ls /
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod
normal
```

**Step 2** 
Now I inserted my USB and opened using live kali and tried to mount terminal using below

```
mkdir /home/temp
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/temp
sudo mount --bind /dev /home/temp/dev
```

the third command gives an error as

> mount mount point /home/temp/dev does not exist

I also tried to mount on /mnt

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

Even its returning the above error

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Check the following link. Very easy to use. https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition

Comment: @SukhjinderSingh , I couldnt repair grub from rescue mode

Comment: I would suggest you to reinstall OS instead of repairing it, because it may time consuming.